# Car is less responsive when moving from 0kmh

Tags: engine

Recently, I noticed that my car ( less than 7000km) is not responsive as before. Now, there is a noticeable delay moving from 0kmh. The strange thing is that the car is still fine after that, it runs just as usual when it starts moving. I feel that the hand break is partly on.

The only thing that suspect is that I refilled it from a gas station that I've never used. It looks a little bit old, might be bad gasoline issue.

Comment: Perhaps it could be old gasoline, but only if the gasoline is several months old at least. What is a possibility is that you used the wrong pump and got a different grade, as you were unfamiliar with the station...